# How to get all the columns that are in different tables in different schemas of my DB postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I want to list all the columns of my tables in postgresql, for that I tried :

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'espace_vert'
AND table_name   = 'diag_arbre_phytosanitaire'
```

I got that :

[image: my result]

That works only for a given schema name and given table name, the thing is I have lots of schemas and inside of them I have lots of tables, so I'm looking for a method that loops over all my schemas and gets all the columns of my tables.

Comment: Have you tried to simply omit the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Actually if I remove the `WHERE` clause it lists all the columns in my DB. Is there anyway I can create some columns in my result and classify them by schemas?

Comment: "Actually if I remove the `WHERE` clause it lists all the columns in my DB." -- Which is what you wrote you want... So that's the solution, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it's the solution thank you very much :)

Comment: `SELECT table_schema, column_name... ORDER BY column_name, table_schema` OR  `SELECT table_schema, column_name... ORDER BY table_schema, column_name`.